# Changing immutable variable in Scala

Tags: scala, overriding

I have a trait `Usertest` in which i have an immutable variable `name` and a mutable variable `age`. While declaring I have initialized `name` with an empty string I made a class `Student` with a constructor having variable `name` and `Student` class extends `Usertest`.

Now I want to change the value of name whenever I make an instance of `Student` but I dont know how to do it.

I have tried it like this:

```
trait Usertest {
  val name: String = ""
  var age: Int= 12

  def setage(setage: Int) = {
    age = setage
  }

   def getAge :Int = age
   def getName : String = name

}

class Student(name : String) extends Usertest

object Main extends App {
  val st = new Student("ahsen")
  var age = st.setage(23)
  println("name  : " st.name)
  println("age : "+ st.getAge)

}
```

It gives this output on console:

> **name :**
>
> **age :23**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did not override the `name` member, only defined a class constructor parameter with the same name. You should add `val` to the parameter:

```
class Student(override val name : String)
```

A `case class` would do this for you silently.

Note: Your code also includes other constructs not idiomatic in Scala, like defining getters and setters - uniform access principle makes this redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, simply `setage` does not return anything (or better, it returns `Unit`, represented as `()`).

You can achieve the whole thing in a much simpler and idiomatic way:

```
case class Student(name: String, var age: Int = 12)

object main extends App {
  val student = Student("ahsen")
  student.age = 23
  println(s"name: ${student.name}, age: ${student.age}") // "name: ahsen, age: 12"
}
```

Even better, you should avoid mutable variables altogether and simply create a new instance when you need to change a property of the object, using the `copy` constructor. Like so

```
case class Student(name: String, age: Int = 12)

object main extends App {
  val student = Student("ahsen")
  val newStudent = student.copy(age = 23)
  println(s"name: ${student.name}, age: ${student.age}") // "name: ahsen, age: 12"
  println(s"name: ${newStudent.name}, age: ${newStudent.age}") // "name: ahsen, age: 23"
}
```

Comment: "Your code is working" - I would disagree. The `getname` in the `Usertest` trait does not return the `name` passed to the `student` constructor, which is probably what was intended. On the positive side, your suggested Scala code looks really idiomatic.

Comment: @Suma "it's working" in a formal way. It returns `Unit`, which is not intended, I agree.

Comment: Unit is returned by a setter, which I would consider a minor stylistic problem (normally one would probably write : Unit explicitly). What I mean by "it is not working" is about `getname` not returning the `name` from `student` (but here I am repeating myself), which is what was a surprise for the OP.